# How to insert all array data into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

How to insert all array data into mysql ?

i want to insert all array string in to mysql , can i do that ?

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
    {
        $myArray[$i] = $i;
    }
$sql = "INSERT INTO table
( all_array , user )
VALUES
('array($myArray)' , '11');";
$dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: What is a type of `all_array`?

Comment: What is your desired result? All values in separate rows, or in the same row somehow or...?

Comment: You can't store array's in mysql.

Comment: Joachim Isaksson  - all of string array like `"1","2","3","4"`

Comment: @user3769723 If you're going to do searches on that array later, you'll get problems if storing an array like that. In that case, you're better off normalizing the database and put each value in a separate row.

Comment: You need to learn [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save all array in json type. But you should not use mysql_* functions, use PDO.

For example:

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
    {
        $myArray[$i] = $i;
    }

$json_array = json_encode($myArray);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table
( all_array , user )
VALUES
('$json_array' , '11');";
$dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: are you positive you can store json array in mysql database( i guess you can as text, longtext, binary or blob) but why would you? why not just write it to a json file at that point, its obviously a better alternative. it will be faster fetching from disk, and more importantly doesn't waste db processing power and query cache. storing arrays of anytype in mysql seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: ok, and if i want to convert this data `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` to array again , how can i do ?

Comment: @r3wt There are hundred of thousands of times you need to store arrays in database. So the best option is to store them either by json or after serializing. What is bad idea in it?

Comment: @user3769723 you can convert to array via json_decode($json_array,TRUE);

Comment: @AwaisQarni the path of least resistance would be to write it to a json file, then read it in with file get contents, json decode it and work with it. you can store the name of the json file in the db to keep track of your json files.

Comment: @r3wt Don't you think its a overhead to rite on a file, then storing the name, the extracting the name, then reading the file?

Comment: @AwaisQarni Its *by far* less overhead to write it to a json file. A mysql database is comprised of multiple files, and requires reading andd writing to dis and uses alot of Random IO, where as writing directly to a file uses sequential IO.

Comment: If this is so then why we are in need to database? Why we cannot save our all values to files?

Comment: @AwaisQarni because RDBMS make our life much easier than writing to hundreds of files. I'm simply proposing a better solution for this particular scenario as an alternative to storing the json in the database, which could become costly beginning on the size of the arrays, as well as the structure and collation of the database and its tables.

Comment: @r3wt Yes as you said RDBMS has made our life much easier than writing to hundreds of files. My dear if you are having large array then it will also cost writing a file. You are doing two steps, 1 writing a file doing to one IO operation, 2, storing the name of file in database another IO operation. And same when you need to extract. Why you don't opt to do one step in both cases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56507/discussion-between-r3wt-and-awais-qarni).

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's `implode` function to join array elements with a string.

```
$arrayAsAString = implode(",", $myArray);
```

NOTE: I just saw @onuri 's answer. So consider this an alternative.

CAVEAT: Performing database queries would be tough, whichever method you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Use php `implode` function, it will break all the elements of your array into comma separated string. Change your code as below.

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
    {
        $myArray[$i] = $i;
    }
$arrayString= implode(", ", $myArray);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table
( all_array , user )
VALUES
('$arrayString' , '11');";
$dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

[Check out this link for details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$json_array = implode(", ", $myArray);`?

Comment: @Thauwa what makes you think `implode` returns a valid json-string or has anything to do with json?

Comment: Umm... I never thought so. Neither did I claim as such. Are you referring to the variable name I used? I was quoting from the answer given.

Answer (score 0):

i would do that with json

```
<?PHP
    include("connect.php");
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) 
    {
        $myArray[$i] = $i;
    }

    $myJSON = json_encode($myArray);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table ( all_array , user ) VALUES ('$myJSON' , '11');";
    $dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

this will return the array as a JSON-String which can be stored in db. if i select it later i can easy transform the JSON-String back to an array if neede like:

```
$myArray = json_decode($myJSONString);
```

Comment: ups, i've should read other posts before... someone had the same answere. :)